# Symfony2 PHP Limit one user sessions 20

Tags: php, symfony, session, limit

I'm looking for a way that a user can enter 10 times simultaneous, if a user logs more (User 11) is to assess whether the nonexistent simultaneous sessions no users with more than 30 minutes connected, if this happens, it is disconnected the oldest, allowing the new user (User 11) enter.

If the 10 users are less than 30 minutes, display an error message, not allowing admission.

Answer (score 0):

It remains only to create a table where the session is saved, consult whenever one enters to delete the value. Adionalmente, you must create a script to poll worker each N seconds and close the session if already exceeded 20.

This was resolved